# How can I open a .7z file in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, compression, 7-zip

How can I open a .7z file in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 28):

You can get 7zip on ubuntu by using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
```

Answer (score 11):

once you have 7zip installed, you can extract an archive like this:

```
$ 7z x foo.7z
```

Comment: I know this is a very noob question, but could you please point me to a reference page where I can understand the meaning of the symbols (e.g. $) and the syntax? Thanks

Comment: @Sosi this means that you are using command line on unix with no root rights. When you open a terminal program on ubuntu you see something like this `dk@dk-l:~/Soft$` which is you user name, your host name and the path to the current working directory. This ends with a symbol `$` or `#`. The latter means that you have root rights on the system. You need to read some book about Linux basics

Answer (score 1):

Thats the file format for 7zip archives. You can grab the 7zip software from [here](http://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

**EDIT:** If you're new to 7zip/Linux, some useful advice can be found on [this page](http://www.howtoadvice.com/7zipHelper/).

Answer (score 1):

File Roller in GNOME does just fine. It is compatible with p7zip, and will allow you to create 7zip archives just right.

Answer (score 0):

[PeaZip](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/) is an awesome (GUI) tool for opening most archives.